# how to system.out.println on the same line(java)

Tags: java

I am totally a beginner in java. Just started it today.

let us suppose a,b and c are 3 objects that i want to print.

AND i want the output as:

```
a b c
```

NOT

```
a  
b    
c
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.out.print()`.  `System.out.println()` prints your string, then moves to a **new line**.  Check the `Javadoc` for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html